# Generics with Spock Stub

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, groovy, spock

I cannot make compile Spock stub for generic class. The signature of constructor is following:

```
SomeClass(SerSup<Cap> capSup, String foo, String bar);
```

I need to stub the first argument. The following are my failed attempts.

First try:

```
def someClass = new SomeClass(Stub(SerSup<Cap>), "foo", "bar")

Error: Groovyc: unexpected token: >
Status bar: ',' or ')' expected
```

Another try:

```
def someClass = new someClass(Stub(Cup) as SerSup<Cup>, "foo" ,"bar")

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.get() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: grep(), getAt(java.lang.String), grep(java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), wait(long)

at loom.SomeClass.SomeMethod(SomeClassTest.groovy:14)
```

What is the right way to stub first argument of `SomeClass` constructor?

Comment: Good explanation from @Szymon, however I'd recommend to just drop the generics and use the plain `Stub(SerSub)` here.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings - Thank you. Actually, it doesn't clear to me, how to "drop generics". Generics in my code sample went with test of real classes. Is there some trick to can help to rid of generics? Or what do you meay?

Comment: Java implemented generics by type erasure, that means that they are removed when they are written to the bytecode. So for java `List<String>` will be `List` at runtime. It is perfectly legal (just a warning) to use just `List`. The only error you made ist that you mixed up your types. Using the example you tried to stub `String` instead of `List` and cast that to `List` which does not really work. So just use `Stub(SerSub)` instead of `Stub(Cap)` and it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second attempt failed because you cannot cast `Stub(Cap)` to `SerSup<Cap>`. You would have to `Stub(SerSup)` instead, or you could apply the suggestions I have described below.

I would recommend creating a variable for your stub before initializing `SomeClass`. You can stub generic class using `Stub(type: ...)` constructor, e.g.

```
SerSup<String> serSup = Stub(type: new TypeToken<SerSup<String>>(){}.type) as SerSup<String>
```

This initialization does not produce any warning in your IDE. If you are ok with some warnings you can simplify it to:

```
def serSup = Stub(type: new TypeToken<SerSup<String>>(){}.type)
```

Alternatively, you could try something like:

```
SerSup<String> serSup = Stub(SerSup) {
    get() >> ""
}
```

This alternative solution requires stubbing methods to return valid type, otherwise it returns the equivalent of `new Object()`. In the first case, "default" values are returned, because we satisfied all type checks (e.g. in case of a `String`, an empty string returned).

Here is an example that shows both approaches:

```
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
import spock.lang.Specification

class StubSpec extends Specification {

    def "test stubbing with default value for String"() {
        when:
        SerSup<String> serSup = Stub(type: new TypeToken<SerSup<String>>(){}.type) as SerSup<String>

        then:
        serSup.get() == ""
    }

    def "test stubbing without explicit type"() {
        when:
        SerSup<String> serSup = Stub(SerSup) {
            get() >> "lorem ipsum"
        }

        then:
        serSup.get() == "lorem ipsum"
    }

    static class SerSup<T> {
        private final T obj

        SerSup(T t) {
            this.obj = t
        }

        T get() {
            return obj
        }
    }
}
```